# Как корректно вывести в поле окна Tkinter вывод команды subprocess

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем доброго времени суток! Я изучаю взаимодействие Tkinter и subprocess и не могу понять как результат команды отобразить ввиде корректного текста в окне Tkinter. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

root = Tk()


def printName():
    text1 = subprocess.run(["ping", "ya.ru"], capture_output=True, text=True)
    text.insert(END, str(text1) + '\n')


text = Text(root)
text.grid()
button = Button(root, text='Print information', command=printName)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Пример вывода команды ping в win7]
[image: Пример выполнения программы в Tkinter, IDE PyCharm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Консоль в Windows имеет кодировку DOS (`cp866`), так что надо просто её указать. И текст взять из атрибута `stdout`.

```
    text1 = subprocess.run(["ping", "ya.ru"], capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='cp866').stdout
```

Или можно преобразовать кодировку потом, если по какой-то причине уже прочитали в неправильной.

```
    text1 = subprocess.run(["ping", "ya.ru"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
    text1 = text1.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение мне очень помогло, теперь программа работает как было задумано.